# VBA Runtime Error 5941 on Copying Multiple Tables from one document to other one by one in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy tables from one word document to other word document one by one.

On running the Macro, the first table is copied to other document and then it is throwing following Error

> Run-time error '5941'
>   The requested member of the collection does not exist.

Below is my program

```
Sub copyTable()

    Dim TotalTables As Integer
    TotalTables = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

    i = 1
    Do While (i < TotalTables)
         Set theTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Range
         theTable.Select
         Selection.Copy

         Dim oTarget As Document
         Set oTarget = Documents.Open("D:\Target.docx")
         oTarget.Select
         Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
         Selection.Paste
         i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

The error specified in the title occurs on this line of code:

```
  Set theTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Range
```

Any Help Would Be Much Appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `oTarget` becomes the `ActiveDocument`, so on the second loop you're trying to copy a non-existent table from it, instead of from your original document.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, the problem is due to the use of `Selection` and `ActiveDocument`. For this reason, it's preferable to work with specific objects, rather than generalizations. If an object for each document is declared, and `Ranges` used instead of `Selection`, the code becomes more reliable *and* more understandable to anyone reading it.

Note: When transferring content between two Word documents (or places within a document) it's not necessary to use the Clipboard (copy/paste). Instead, `Range.FormattedText` can be used.

Note: I'm uncertain whether you really mean to open the same document for each iteration of the loop, since it's not being saved. The question also indicates that all tables should be copied to the same document. So I've moved opening the target document outside of the loop.

Note: You could also use `For...Each` to loop all the tables in a document, rather than using a counter.

Note: It's also very important to put `Option Explicit` at the top of a code module.

For example

```
Sub copyTable()
    Dim docTables as Word.Document
    Dim docTarget as Word.Document
    Dim theTable as Word.Table
    Dim rngTarget as Word.Range
    Dim TotalTables As Integer

    Set docTables = ActiveDocument
    TotalTables = docTables.Tables.Count
    Set docTarget = Documents.Open("D:\Target.docx")

    i = 1
    Do While (i < TotalTables)
         Set theTable = docTables.Tables(i)   
         Set rngTarget = docTarget.Content
         rngTarget.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
         rngTarget.Range.FormattedText = theTable.Range.FormattedText
         i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @cindy-meister. I tried your code but it is showing error " compile error - method or data member not found" . 
The error is on line `rngTarget.Range.FormattedText = theTable.Range.FormattedText`  
and on the part **rngTarget.Range.FormattedText**

Comment: @Dhruva I'm not a word-vba expert but I think you need to remove the `Range`: `rngTarget.FormattedText = theTable.Range.FormattedText`.